# CMake Error in src/CMakeLists.txt: GMP_INCLUDES-NOTFOUND

Tags: c++, c, cmake, библиотеки

Я пытаюсь собрать [эту](https://github.com/Chia-Network/bls-signatures) библиотеку под Windows, чтобы использовать её на VS 2019. Следуя инструкции, выполняю:

```bash
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ../
```

Среди прочего вывода CMake выдаёт:

> CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
>
> Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
>
> GMP_INCLUDES (ADVANCED)

И потом несколько десятков ошибок такого вида, как в названии вопроса.

Я собрал gmp по [данной инструкции](https://habr.com/ru/sandbox/53707/), но проблема не ушла.

Вопрос: как указать CMake, где у меня находится gmp, чтобы я смог корректно собрать нужную мне библиотеку?

Comment: А разве вопросы билда тематика SO?

Comment: @V-Mor - "Я собрал gmp по данной инструкции". - В этой инструкции есть такой пункт: "Переносим файлы libgmp-3.lib, gmp.h и libgmp-3.def в папку нашего проекта ". Вы это сделали?